# How can I redirect a website site with a CNAME record using HTTPS

Tags: ssl, redirect, https, dns, cname

I inherited a strangely configured website and I'm trying to setup an SSL certificate but with no luck.

Here's the initial setup.
There are 3 distinct websites with different URLS. Let's say:

- site1.com
- site2.com
- site3.com

All three websites are hosted on the same web hosting provider (same account) but each with their distinct root folder.
`site1.com` has all the files that are needed to show the website while `site2.com` and `site3.com` have the generic default files saying "under construction".

`site2.com` and `site3.com` have a CNAME record setup like so:

```
www.site2.com CNAME www.site1.com
```

and

```
www.site3.com CNAME www.site1.com
```

When I access `www.site2.com` I am able to view site2's content which is distinct from the other two. The code used in the Content Management System is shared for all 3 sites but the CMS looks at the URL it's loaded from and shows a different layout depending on the domain.

So far everything works.

But when I enable `https` and visit `site2.com` or `site3.com` I can only see the default "under construction page" and not the correct content.

I was thinking it had to do with the domain name and SSL certificate so I bought a multi-domain SSL certificate with all 3 domains and installed it on `site1.com` since the other sites are kind of mirroring that one.

Even with the multi-domain SSL certificate, I'm still seeing the "under construction" pages when I visit `site2.com` and `site3.com`.

I also tried installing the multi-domain on `site2.com` and `site3.com` but that didn't do anything also.

Does anyone know why it stops working when I add https in front of `site2.com` and `site3.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not related to CNAME or the certificate. The problem is that the configuration of your web server has no specific setup for site2 and site3.

A CNAME just helps to resolve the IP address for site2 and site3 to the one from site1.  A CNAME is just an DNS level alias for a domain name and the web server does not know about this. This means that the name transferred by the browser to the server is still site2 or site3 and not site1 and thus the server will take the site2 or site3 specific configuration and not the one for site1.

This means you need to adjust your servers configuration so that the one for site1 will also be used for site2 and site3. How exactly this needs to be done depends on your specific web server. Since nothing is known about this server and its setup no further help about this can be done.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Is there anything I can provide that would help pinpoint what needs to be setup correctly?

Comment: @VVV:  To cite myself: *"This means you need to adjust your servers configuration so that the one for site1 will also be used for site2 and site3. Since nothing is known about this server and its setup no further help about this can be done."* - thus please refer to the documentation of your specific but unknown web server of how to do this within your specific but unknown server setup.

Comment: My apologies, I misread your phrase. I'll have to look into this but since this is on a shared hosing plan, I don't think I'm able to adjust the server's configuration. Thank you for your reply.